# Why won't the Saml2SecurityHandler create a token using ReadToken from a string I've just created using WriteToken?

Tags: security, serialization, token, access-token, saml-2.0

So I need to serialize a token to send to a service via a queue + NetMessageBinding in Azure.  The token comes from ACS and after some jiggery pokery I have the Saml2SecurityToken and I can write it to a string:

```
SecurityTokenHandlerCollection handlers = SecurityTokenHandlerCollection.CreateDefaultSecurityTokenHandlerCollection();
var saml2SecurityToken = securityToken as Saml2SecurityToken;
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        handlers.WriteToken(xmlWriter, saml2SecurityToken);
    }

    tokenString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.GetBuffer());
}
```

however if I then try and recreate the Saml2SecurityToken from the `tokenString` like so:

```
if (tokenString != null)
{
    using (var stringReader = new StringReader(tokenString))
    {
        using (var xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(stringReader))
        {
            securityToken = handlers.ReadToken(xmlReader);
        }
    }
}
```

or if I use

```
securityToken = handlers.ReadToken(tokenString);
```

then securityToken is always null.

What am I missing?  How can I go about serialising my token so I can send it via wcf to another service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D'oh, it was probably some encoding issue as if I get the string using this then everything works ok:

```
var saml2SecurityToken = securityToken as Saml2SecurityToken;

var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
using (var xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(stringBuilder, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
{
    handlers.WriteToken(xmlWriter, saml2SecurityToken);
}
```